# Redirect requests on alternate port for Apache virtual host

Tags: apache, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, vhost

I have Apache server where I make my LoadBalancer for my application sereres through proxy and balancermember. Some of my clients come from legacy access, they use a port in the URL `example.com:2030` as informed by the old team. So vhost is that way.

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:2030>
```

I would like to force them to just 80 with a redirect to `example.com`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80 *:2030>
> ```

Separate the vHosts, so that port 2030 has its own container and implement a site-wide redirect in that container to port 80 (or HTTPS/443?). For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:2030>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    # Redirect everything to port 80
    Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

HOWEVER, aren't you using HTTPS (port 443)? Or maybe this is handled by the front-end proxy? In which case the above should redirect to `https://....`.